# How to display pdf in Webview if url contains embed html data?

Tags: android, html, embed

Below I'm sharing html response
<!doctype html><embed name='E80E07CEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' style='position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;'width='100%' height='100%' src='about:blank' type='application/pdf' internalid='E80E97CEFXXXXXXXXXXXXX'>

Please help me on this.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

i think you should upload pdf on your google drive, and link it to the page :)

Comment: Actually we got pdf embed data from another application so i dont have another option it was working fine in IOS and web in iframe.